# What is the replacement for FielddataLoading.Eager option in Elasticsearch mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am upgrading an app from Elasticsearch 2.3 to 7.9. I'm using the NEST client version 7.11.1 which shows to be compatible with ES 7.9. We are using 7.9 because that is the latest version version available on AWS server we are working with.

The old application has the following field mapping:

```
.String(s => s
    .Name(f => f.PartDescription)
    .Analyzer(Analyzers.DescriptionAnalyzer)
    .Fielddata(descriptor => descriptor.Loading(FielddataLoading.Eager)));
```

I am using the following mapping to replace this in the new version:

```
.Text(t => t
    .Name(ep => ep.PartDescription)
    .Analyzer(Analyzer.DescriptionAnalyzer)
    .Fielddata(true))
```

I see that in the new version the only option for Fielddata is a boolean. The Eager and other options are missing.

Is Fielddata(true) a suitable equivalent for the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean on `fielddata` determines whether `fielddata` is enabled for the field. `fielddata` is used when performing aggregations, sorting and for scripting, and is loaded into the heap, into the fielddata cache, on demand (not eagerly loaded).

Typically for [`text` datatype fields, you don't want `fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param); `text` data types undergo analysis and the resulting tokens are stored in the inverted index. When `fielddata` is set to `true`, the inverted index is uninverted on demand to produce a columnar structure that is loaded into the heap to serve aggregations, sorting and scripting on `text` fields. Text analysis often produces many tokens that serve the purpose of full-text search well but don't serve the purpose of aggregation, sorting and scripting well. With *many* tokens and *many* concurrent aggregations, heap memory can grow quickly, exerting GC pressure. So, the default for `text` datatype fields is to have `fielddata` be `false`, and to set it to `true` if you know what you're doing.

Instead of setting `fielddata` to `true` on a `text` datatype field, a good approach is to [use multi-fields and also map the field as a `keyword` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html) if the field is one that you want to use for aggregations, sorting and scripting, and target the `keyword` multi field for this purpose.

Comment: That was easy! I removed the Fielddata(true) setting from these fields and everything still works. I'm not sure why the developers on the old application used that setting but it appears it was redundant since the fields are not used for sorting or aggregations.